# Make the dumb components a tad smarter

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I enjoy react and I also enjoy the use of

```
export default props => (
    <div className="SuperStyled">
        {props.textMain}
        <div className="moreDetail">
           {props.textSub}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

allowing me to quickly used special styled components on the run. But I discovered if I do something a tad more detailed I could started building out my pages *even* quicker with small styling in the component calling.

```
export default props => (
    <div className={'SuperStyled ' + props.textColor + " " + props.shadowColor}>
        {props.textMain}
        <div className="moreDetail">
           {props.textSub}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

That's when I noticed that if I don't I pass through the `props.textColor` it defaults as `undefined`. Which sorta makes sense.

Is there anyway to check within this style of component that if *props* were not passed it would default to something (such as `' '`)?

Comment: You can use defaultProps for this case

Comment: Also, using the [_classnames_](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) lib really cleans this up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
const MyComponent = props => (
     <div className={'SuperStyled ' + props.textColor + " " + props.shadowColor}>
          {props.textMain}
          <div className="moreDetail">
            {props.textSub}
          </div>
      </div>
)

MyComponent.defaultProps = { // you can set default/fallback value here for the props
    textColor: '', 
    shadowColor: ''
}
export default MyComponent;
```